# Локально развернутая бд на сервере или бд хостинг

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, сервер

Допустим есть небольшой проект, который развернут на небольшом dns сервере.

Имеется бд (postgesql), которая в свою очередь не требует большого кол-ва памяти и скорости. Что лучше, локально развернуть бд на этом сервере или все таки купить бд хостинг, на котором будет она лежать?

Answer (score 2):

Лично я бы развернул там, где могу, где хост "посвободне" и настроил бы мониторинг. По факту уже посмотрел бы сколько ресурсов оно ест и уже потом делал бы выводы - переносить на отдельный хостинг или оставить как есть.

Comment: Допустим на сервере хватало бы места для базы, то тогда оставить ее там? Если да, то почему?

Answer (score 0):

1)Если есть желание развивать проект, то конечно если есть возможность, лучше БД хостинг.

2)Если забавы ради или для собственного опыта, можно все оставить и как есть. В таком случае вариант с локальным развертыванием тоже не плох!

Comment: Было бы неплохо пояснить плюсы и минусы)